# retrieve only favoured posts from firebase

Tags: swift, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve only posts that I have liked from firebase database.

below is my data. I want this user who has liked a post to only show that post if that post was liked by that user.

I am already retrieving data from firebase but it will show all posts not just favoured ones.

[image]

This code below is what I am using and it works in that it shows the data if I hit like and doesn't if I unlike, but this is showing all data.

```
        DataService.ds.REF_USER_CURRENT.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if snapshot.hasChild("favourite") {

                print("true Favourits exist")


    DataService.ds.REF_POSTS.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        self.posts = []

        if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
            for snap in snapshot {
                print("SNAP: \(snap)")
                if let postDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                    let key = snap.key
                    let post = Post(postKey: key, postData: postDict)
                    self.posts.append(post)
                }
            }
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()

        })
            }else {
                print("Tony: Couldnt get the data")
            }

    })
}
```

EDITED FROM HERE WITH VLADS ANSWER>>>>>>>

```
DataService.ds.REF_USER_CURRENT.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if snapshot.hasChild("favourite") {


    let refToUser = DataService.ds.REF_USER_CURRENT // <- your userId
    refToUser.child("favourite").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let postsIds = value?.allKeys as! [String]

        for postId in postsIds {
            let refToPost = Database.database().reference(withPath: "posts/" + postId)
            refToPost.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                if snapshot.exists() {
                self.notAddedLabel.isHidden = true
                print("true Favourits exist")


//      refToPost.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        self.posts = []

        if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
            for snap in snapshot {
                print("SNAP: \(snap)")
                if let postDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                    let key = snap.key
                    let post = Post(postKey: key, postData: postDict)
                    self.posts.append(post)
                }
            }
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()

//          })
            }else {
                self.notAddedLabel.isHidden = false
                print("Tony: Couldn't get the data")
                }
            })
        }
      })
         }else {
            print("Tony: No Favs added, couldn't get the data")
    }
})
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`First step:` go to `favourite` node and get all posts id's:

```
let refToUser = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "Users").child(userId) // <- your userId
refToUser.child("favourite").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        if let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let postsIds = value.allKeys as! [String]

        // Second step: fetch every post
        for postId in postsIds {
            let refToPost = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "posts/" + postId)
            refToPost.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                 if snapshot.exists() {
                     // do whatever you want
                     // snapshot now is your post data
                 } else {
                     print("error")
                 }
            })
        }
```

So, your main problem, that you are making reference to all posts, not to specific ones.

Hope you got the idea.

Comment: Yes thank you @VladPulichev. it works in a way and i understand what you mean, my issue in my head was pulling from users/favourites would only bring down a post key so your explanation really helped. The only problem I'm having is it seems to pull the correct data down now for posts only liked it shows this in console, but its not displaying to my table cell like it was when pulling all data down. I have edited my question with a picture showing the console and the the function with your edit.

Comment: @TonyMerritt you need to get array of data with all needable posts. Like function with completion handler. Then update table view. But I think I have answered main question:)

Comment: I think I have that already in place I probably need to read through the cod and see where i need to edit. like i said it worked with all data. Thank you for your time @Vlad.... you definitely answered the question for me..

Comment: Thank you for your help on this @VladPulichev, I refactored my code on to call the table reload and got it working all thanks to you. I really appreciate your help.......

Comment: @TonyMerritt Glad to hear it:)